# Return Value from Server to App

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am programming the login/register functionality of my app and have everything in order so far.

When a user logins in, my php script returns a 1 if successful, and a 0 if unsuccessful. The same is true when they try to register.

My question in, how do I get my app to recognize what value is returned from the php function and respond accordingly?

```
- (int) authenticateClient {
NSString *loginWeb = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"http://localhost/login.php?uname=%@&pass=%@&submit=Log%%20In"), user, pass];
NSURL *login = [NSURL URLWithString:loginWeb];
NSData *loginData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: login];
NSMutableURLRequest *loginRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[loginRequest setURL:login];
[loginRequest setTimeoutInterval:10];
```

Comment: You need provide more information. Show the code where you make the request and handle the response. And what part of handling the response has you confused? Also your app doesn't know your server is PHP. It's simply going to make a request and get back a response.

Comment: Your code looks confused. First you get a data object by using dataWithContentsOfURL, and then you set up a URLRequest. What is that for? It looks like you're setting up to do an NSURLConnection, which is probably what you should do in the first place. What form is the data that you expect back from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create an API for your mobile app to access. In the php script you could echo back a json container for the data you want to retrieve, and have your app parse the body as json and perform whatever action necessary.